# Check all tables, columns and types in redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

Hi i'm trying to find the tables and columns and types for all my sachems not only the public one in redshift

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [System Tables Reference - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/cm_chap_system-tables.html).

For example: [PG_TABLE_DEF](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_PG_TABLE_DEF.html) stores information about table columns:

```
select "column", type, encoding, distkey, sortkey, "notnull" 
from pg_table_def
where tablename = 'lineorder_compound' 
and sortkey <> 0;

column       | type    | encoding | distkey | sortkey | notnull
-------------+---------+----------+---------+---------+--------
lo_orderkey  | integer | delta32k | false   |       1 | true   
lo_custkey   | integer | none     | false   |       2 | true   
lo_partkey   | integer | none     | true    |       3 | true   
lo_suppkey   | integer | delta32k | false   |       4 | true   
lo_orderdate | integer | delta    | false   |       5 | true   
(5 rows)
```

Comment: Betsy probably does this but sees only public schema, she needs to run `set search_path to public, schema1, schema2, etc.` first to be able to see other schemas in `pg_table_def` output

Answer (score 0):

@John I have looked at System table references and main issue is that it can only look at tables and columns within the base tables.

I need to just pull views created from these tables and show only columns within the views not base tables that they are based on.